# array switch case statement

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I have an array coming in with sub arrays like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customers] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 

                )

            [Products] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 

                )

            [Models] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 151


                    [SubModels] => Array
                        (
                            [ol] => 
                        )

                    [Noice] => 
                )

        )
```

I want to make a switch statement on the array

so something like this

```
switch($array){

    case Products:

    case customers:

    case Models:
}
```

how would I do that.
Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

since $array holds an array within it, it looks like you'll actually want to look at the keys of the array indexed at $array[0]

```
foreach ($array[0] as $key => $value) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'Products' :
            // do something
            break ;
        case 'customers' :
            // do something
            break ;
        case 'Models' :
            // do something
            break ;
     }
 }
```